# Laravel catch Artisan:call exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, try-catch, laravel-artisan

I want to catch the error form `Artisan::call()` method. For example if i don't have data in table `migrations` and when i run `Artisan::call('migrate:make');` i get error  `Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists` in log file.

I try to use try catch, but it doesn't work.

```
            try {
                Artisan::call('migrate:make');
            } catch (Exception $e){
                report($e);

                Mail::to(config('mail.supportEmail'))->send(new UserProblemMail($data, "Migrate error"));

                return response()->json([
                    "message" => "Error occured. Suport team will contact with you."
                ], 500);
            }
```

How do this properly?

Comment: I think that `Artisan` calls are separate instances, and a `try/catch` around the caller won't handle errors inside the command. You'd need to `try/catch` the error in the actual command and send a different return code on error, but I've never actually done that, so you'd need to do some Googling to figure out that approach.

Comment: So when I use `$resp = Artisan::call('migrate:make');` i should get some response?

Comment: Even when error in this command will occur? I try to do this, but it's look like that this error is breaking function and don't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my way to handle this situation.

```
try{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    
    Artisan::call('migrate');
    $artisanOutput = Artisan::output();

    if (in_array("Error", str_split($artisanOutput, 5))) {
        throw new Exception($artisanOutput);
    }

    DB::commit();

    dd("Deployed Successfully", ['Artisan output' => $artisanOutput]);
} catch (Exception | Error $e) {
    DB::rollback();

    dd($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command to catch output :

```
Artisan::call('migrate:make');
dd(Artisan::output());
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 